# Count Same Elements In ng-repeat Angular

Tags: angularjs, grouping, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have one array which provide me the movies list i want to count the number of movies which belong to same category.

My Js

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.movies = [
           { title: 'The Matrix', rating: 7.5, category: 'Action' },
           { title: 'Focus', rating: 6.9, category: 'Comedy' },
           { title: 'The Lazarus Effect', rating: 6.4, category: 'Thriller' },
           { title: 'Everly', rating: 5.0, category: 'Action' },
           { title: 'Maps to the Stars', rating: 7.5, category: 'Drama' }
    ];
});
```

My Html

```
<div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Rating</th>
                        <th>Category</th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr ng-repeat="data in movies | filter:query">
                    <td>{{data.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.rating}}</td>
                    <td>{{data.category}}</td>


                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Now i m showing data on view page using ng-repeat what i want is i want to display category of movies and and the no of movies which falls in that category 
For Example Let Us Say:

```
Actions(2) // No Of Count
Everly //Movie Name
The Matrix // Movie Name
```

i want output in my ng-repeat in abov mention way how can i do so.. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it can be written using custom filters,
you can use already written utils from this module
https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

It provides filter groupBy and many other utils which can used for grouping by

Include this script

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-   filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js"></script>
```

And inject the module into your main app

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", ['angular.filter']);
```

Then your display logic is as simple as

```
 <div ng-controller="MyController"> 
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in movies | groupBy: 'category'">
      Group name: {{ key }} {{value.length}}
      <li ng-repeat="movie in value">
        movie: {{ movie.title }} 
      </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

For displaying the count note the expression {{value.length}}

You can check for the optimized filter logic in the source code of the angular-filter.

Answer (score 2):

**Try** to use filter with your `ng-repeat`

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in movies | filter:{category: 'Action'}">
    <td>{{data.title}}</td>
    <td>{{data.rating}}</td>
    <td>{{data.category}}</td>
</tr>
```

*It will work in display your filtered category, but if you need to count it. You need to calculate it in your controller which will be present in examples below*

**Or** you can do it in your controller, by looping through your `$scope.movies` with a for loop. Or use the underscoreJS javascript plugin.

```
$scope.movies.action = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.movies.lenth; i++){
    if($scope.movies[i].category == 'Action'){
        $scope.moveies.action.push($scope.movies[i]);
    }
}
// $scope.movies.actions.length; number of action movie
```

**Or** with Angular javascript filter

```
$scope.movies.action = $filter('filter')($scope.movies, {category: 'Action'});
// $scope.movies.actions.length; number of action movie
```

**Or** with underscore

```
$scope.movies.action = _.filter($scope.movies, funtion(movie){
    return movie.category == 'Action'; 
});
// $scope.movies.actions.length; number of action movie
```

And your HTML will look like this with counter of movie in filtered category

```
<tr><td>Action: {{movies.action.lenth}}</td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="data in movies | filter:{category: 'Action'}">
    <td>{{data.title}}</td>
    <td>{{data.rating}}</td>
    <td>{{data.category}}</td>
</tr>
```

*Edit: some typo and add the counter with javascript solution*